# Does the community edition of VoltDB support Passive Database Replication?

Tags: voltdb

I tried some experiments that I want to know the differences between the community of VoltDB and the enterprise.And I did this:

```
    1. I wrote some words into the deployment.xml of the Master Cluster:
       <dr id="1" />
    2. Then I started the Master Cluster successd.
       [The Master Cluster started successfully.][https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO5e9.png]


    3. I wrote some words into the deployment.xml of the Replica Cluster:
       <dr id="2">
           <connection source="voltsvr1" />
       </dr>
    4. I created a table into the Master Cluster:
       CREATE TABLE STORE (
       KEYSPACE varbinary(128) NOT NULL,
       KEY varchar(128) NOT NULL,
       VALUE varbinary(2056) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (KEYSPACE, KEY)
       );
       PARTITION TABLE STORE ON COLUMN KEY;
       DR TABLE STORE;

    5. Then I started the Replica Cluster with --replica option:
       [The Replica Cluster started successfully.][https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zbxJ.png]


    6. I used the same statements to create a same table store like the  table in the      Master Cluster:
       CREATE TABLE STORE (
       KEYSPACE varbinary(128) NOT NULL,
       KEY varchar(128) NOT NULL,
       VALUE varbinary(2056) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (KEYSPACE, KEY)
       );
       PARTITION TABLE STORE ON COLUMN KEY;
       DR TABLE STORE;

    7. I loaded some data into the table store of the Master Cluster, but   the table store of Replica Cluster could't get data from the Master Cluster.
```

I want to know what's the problem？
Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database Replication is not available in the community edition of VoltDB.  XDCR (active/active, active/passive), high availability, export, and full durability are only available in the Enterprise Edition.  Our github wiki page offers a brief description of the differences here: 
https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb#commercial-voltdb-differences

Thanks,

John